# lein jar to contain both project.clj and pom.xml

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

When I run `$ lein jar` the created jar file contains a `META-INF/maven/groupId/artifactId/project.clj` file.

When I run `$ mvn package` the created jar file contains a `META-INF/maven/groupId/artifactId/pom.xml`.

How can is setup Leiningen so that both files would be available inside the created jar file? Thank you in advance.

Comment: pom.xml is a maven file you can't copy it in the jar with other build system, try to find a plugin like maven-assembly in leiningen to copy the pom.xml into the jar